# mapping a series to two columns from dataset object array

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am using an array of objects with the following structure:

```
dimensions: [
 'date',
 'uploadedBy',
 'uploadedTo',
 'total',
 'attributeCount',
 'segmentAssignmentCount'
],
```

The xAxis is the date. I need one stack for total, one for attributeCount and one for segmentAssignmentCount. On each stack there should be one bar for each uploadedBy/uploadedTo combination.

Is there a way to encode the series to get this in conjunction to datasource, or will I have to iterate through the data and construct the series data manually?

I have been breaking my head with this, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried following this [tutorial](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Dataset)? If yes and not successful please provide data example or a picture of how it should look.

Comment: I ended up iterating over the data to generate the series, as there was no one to one equivalence series to fields. Is working fine :)